# In bash, how to catch and handle SIGINT, without stopping the script?

Tags: bash, signals, sigint

It looks like

```
trap on_sigint SIGINT
```

just stop the script as soon as `SIGINT` is caught. Then, `on_sigint` is executed.
Is it possible to handle `SIGINT` without stopping the script ?

Comment: What does your `on_sigint` do? Can you show your code? The script will only stop if your handler for SIGINT exits the script.

Comment: The function is : `on_SIGINT () {
    echo '<< SIGINT received >>' ;
    stop=1 ; echo 'Will stop.'}`

Comment: You know that script names are case sensitive, right? So if your interrupt handler is named `on_SIGINT` and you are doing `trap on_sigint`, then your trap won't be executed. You should add your code to your problem description. And is there some other part of the script looking at `stop` and exiting if it is `1`?

Comment: Sorry for the case, I mis-copied. The stop is supposed to be used to break a loop with `[[ -n $stop ]] && break`, but we are going away from the question.

Comment: see also [Catch SIGINT in bash, handle AND ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785522/catch-sigint-in-bash-handle-and-ignore)

Answer (score 7):

`SIGINT` does not kill the script after the handler runs. Here is a small, self contained test case:

```
trap on_sigint SIGINT
on_sigint() { echo "caught"; }

{ sleep 3; kill -SIGINT $$; } &

echo "Waiting for sigint"
sleep 5
echo "Still running"
```

The output is:

```
Waiting for sigint
caught
Still running
```

If your observation was correct, the last line would not have been there.

Comment: You are right, the problem seems to happend only when pressing ^C to interrupt the command. It looks like it first interrupt the running command of the script, then handle the signal.