# When trapping SIGINT in bash what effect does the -- have in the trap command?

Tags: bash, sigint

I've been reading various posts about handling `SIGINT` in `bash`, but I still don't properly understand it.

I know that `trap '_handler_name' SIGINT` runs `_handler_name` when the signal is received.  (People always seem to put it in single quotes, but I don't know why.  It doesn't seem necessary to me.)

I was hoping to be able to trap `SIGINT` and handle it without aborting a loop in my script, but that only seems to work when the loop is in its own subshell.  (I don't know why that is...)

I had thought that using `trap -- '_handler_name' SIGINT` might somehow stop other parts of the script from aborting when the signal is received.  (This is based upon my reading of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498490/1999993).)

So my main question is: what effect does the `--` have on `trap`.  I thought that always just meant "that's the end of the switches" but the example I was looking at didn't have a `-` after that, so it looks redundant.

And sub-questions that would help my understanding are: what effect does `trap` have on subshells? and why do people put the handler name in quotes in the `trap` command?

For context, what I'm trying to do is spot a SIGINT, politely kill a couple of processes, then wait for a few seconds for everything to finish before exiting manually.

PS [This article](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) was interesting, though I didn't manage to get my solution from reading it.

---

**UPDATE:** I've moved what was here to a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70577697/1999993), since it turns out that what I'm asking here isn't the cause of the issue I've observed.

Comment: There are many question in your post. It's better to make the post concise, limited to one single short problem./ `I don't know why that is` Create a separate question, present a full [MCVE], present the input that you are getting, the input that you expected to get.

Comment: `I would expect the same output as in the first case.` You changed the condition, `read line` fails, either reads 0 or receives `SIGHUP` - the other side gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what effect does the -- have on trap

Yes, it `just means "that's the end of the switches"`. https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/trap.def#L110 -> https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/builtins/bashgetopt.c#L85

> what effect does trap have on subshells?

From bash manual command execution environment https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment :

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that consists of the following. Unless otherwise noted, the values are inherited from the shell.
>
> ...
>
> - traps caught by the shell are reset to the values inherited from the shell’s parent, and traps ignored by the shell are ignored
>
> ...
>
> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught by the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation.

Also below near `trap` builtin:

> Trapped signals that are not being ignored are reset to their original values in a subshell or subshell environment when one is created.

Also `errexit` is relevant specifically for `ERR`.

> why do people put the handler name in quotes in the trap command?

Cosmetics. Because `trap` re-evals the string, it's a visual cue that it's a string to be re-evaled, not list of words.

Comment: Since this answers my title question, I think it's only right to mark it as the solution - thanks!  I'll add a new question to address what it turns out I actually need to know...